# Получить значение строки после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: c#, xaml, события, uwp

Очень нужна ваша помощь:

Есть `TextBlock1.Text`, который выводит год.
При нажатии на кнопку, год увеличивается на `1`.

Как мне получить этот `TextBlock1.Text` в другом классе, чтобы он также реагировал на событие кнопки, увеличивая значение на `1`? В классе `class2` я буду использовать его в структуре `DateTime`.

Пример кода:

```
class class1
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    TextBlock1.Text = now.ToString("yyyy"); // 2019

    public void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(TextBlock1.Text);
        i++;
        TextBlock1.Text = i.ToString(); // Увеличивает год на 1 при нажатии на кнопку
    }
}

class class2
{
    TextBlock1.Text // Как его получить, чтобы он также работал, как и в первом
    // классе, каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку, 
    // увеличиваясь на 1.
}
```

Или же, если есть более правильный способ, подскажите с реализацией:

Все тоже самое, только во втором классе `class2` у меня структура `DateTime` принимает параметры года, который должен увеличиваться на один при нажатии на кнопку в первом классе `class1`:

```
class class2
{
    public readonly int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); // здесь мне надо
    // вместо year указать год, который увеличивается на 1 при нажатии на кнопку
    // в первом классе.
}
```

Comment: Научитесь использовать привязки и почитайте про MVVM.

Comment: Когда один объект должен проинформировать другой объект о своем изменении, то для этого есть паттерн Наблюдатель, ну или просто создайте в классе `class` событие типа `EventHandler<int>`, а в `class2` подпишитесь на него. После строки `TextBlock1.Text = i.ToString();` вызывайте это событие и передавайте через его второй аргумент значение `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Подключи библиотеку `MvvmLight`. Почитай про паттерн `MVVM`. Не обязательно, чтобы он рассказывался на примере именно `UWP`, можно и для `WPF` найти, там разницы никакой в самом подходе. Разве что в `WPF` будет `MainViewModel` не в `Code behind` класса `MainWindow`, а в каком-нибудь `ViewModelLocator` или в `XAML` задаваться напрямую в качестве `DataContext`.

[Пример приложения](https://github.com/Casper-SC/Time-Randomizer) с использованием паттерна `MVVM`.

Ответ на твой вопрос, как сделать, чтобы обновлялось значение другого класса и заодно пример с обновлением `UI`

**ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace UpdateDateTime.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private DateTime _date;

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set
            {
                if (Set(ref _date, value))
                {
                    OnDateChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler DateChanged; 

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void IncreaseDate()
        {
            Date = Date.AddYears(1);
        }

        protected void OnDateChanged()
        {
            DateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**Views/MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="UpdateDateTime.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:UpdateDateTime"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        </Style>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock
            Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="0,45,0,0"
            Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Date, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='0000'}" />

        <TextBlock
            Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Date, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='0000'}" />

        <Button
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.IncreaseDate}"
            Content="Увеличить" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Views/MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using UpdateDateTime.ViewModels;

namespace UpdateDateTime
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private SomeClass _someClass;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ViewModel), typeof(MainViewModel), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(MainViewModel)));

        public MainViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (MainViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Отписываться не обязательно, так как у COM объектов слабые ссылки (все события UWP классов)
            Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
        }

        private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.DateChanged -= OnDateChanged;
            ViewModel = null;
            // Если в UI есть x:Bind, то нужно вызывать
            Bindings.StopTracking();
        }

        private void OnDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _someClass.UpdateDays(((MainViewModel)sender).Date.Year, 2);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Days: {_someClass.Days.ToString()}");
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            _someClass = new SomeClass();

            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            ViewModel.DateChanged += OnDateChanged;

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
    }
}
```